# send google cloud message to un-published android app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app in the google play store that I need to change as I have lost the live key.

I want to send a push notification to all the current users to tell them to change apps.

But my question is, I dont want to have 2 apps side by side ideally, so can I un-publish/delete the current one and publish the new one, but then still send a push notification to all the users of the deleted app?

Comment: Please try to be more precise... What kind of push notification? If you are talking about GCM notification : you don't need to have your application published into the play store to use GCM.

Comment: Yes GCM to an android app! Ideal, I will swap the apps over and then send my push to the old app! Thanks